# Diferencias al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado en local y servidor

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, el cual ejecuto de manera local en Workbench y hace lo que necesito; sin embargo, tengo la misma base de datos almacenada en un servidor de prueba, y es ahí donde me muestra el siguiente mensaje cuando lo ejecuto:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Mi base de datos es para un consultorio dental, mi tabla de citas es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE CitaMedica
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Fecha_Registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Fecha_Programada DATE NOT NULL,
    Hora_Programada TIME NOT NULL,
    Motivo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Estado BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    Paciente_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Servicio_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)  
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

El Stored Procedure es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cancelarCita`
(
IN param_id INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT Estado = TRUE FROM CitaMedica WHERE ID = param_id)
    THEN
        DELETE FROM CitaMedica WHERE ID = param_id;
    ELSE 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: No se encontró cita para el paciente.';
COMMIT;
END IF;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

¿Será alguna diferencia en la configuración?

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu Stored Procedure a:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cancelarCita`
(
IN param_id INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM CitaMedica WHERE ID = param_id and Estado = true)>0
    THEN
      BEGIN
        DELETE FROM CitaMedica WHERE ID = param_id;
      END;
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 
        'Error: No se encontró  cita para el paciente.';
      COMMIT;
     END;
   END IF;
   END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar, en tu respuesta, los cambios realizados y por qué estaba mal planteado el procedure del OP?